# when to implement ng2 "services"?

Tags: angular, typescript

What are the general decision rules around when to implement ng2 services? I'm fairly new to ng2 but I was thinking that they should just be used as a wrapper for external API calls.  It seems like any other use could potentially be ambiguous and/or confusing.  Technically, any isolation of logic into an encapsulated class could be considered a "service" but in that case I would simply put this logic into its own class without calling it a "service."

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services

Answer (score 2):

`Angular services` are very helpful not just only writing wrapper for external api or something else but there are a number of use cases where services are very helpful. Some of the use case are described as:

- Angular services can be used to **communicate between components**.
- Angular services are likely to be **singleton** in nature.
- Component should contains logic related to the view and other part should be written in services.
- With the help of services we can share the same logic between different components.

Comment: "With the help of services we can share the same logic between different components."  you can easily do that with classes which are not services

Comment: @user8334943 Services _are_ just classes which Angular knows how to inject, using the `@Injectable()` decorator. ARUN has summed up the reason we use them pretty well, but you can [read mode on Angular services in the official guide](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services). Their name doesn't have to end in _service_ in order to be used as services: injected into other entities of your app.

Comment: thanks for the info lazar.  so what are the minimum attributes which define a service?  sounds like, at a minimum, a service must be @Injectable.  is that the single defining characteristic of a "service" in ng2 or does a service have additional minimum defining characteristics?

Comment: No, a service does *not* require the `@Injectable` decorator unless the service is itself injecting some services into its constructor. The main thing that distinguishes a service from any other "normal" class is that it is registered with the Angular injector and can therefore be injected into other Angular components and services. A service is registered with the Angular injector by defining it in the `providers` array of a component or NgModule.

Comment: @DeborahK It is not required a service to be decorated with `@Injectable`  but If a service using another Injectable service then the service must be Injectable i.e decorated with`@Injectable`. But it is recommended that the service should be Injectable.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @ARUN. I was replying to the OP that said "sounds like, at a minimum, a service must be @Injectable" and as you stated as well, that is not the case. Thanks for clarifying.